# IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

Подскажите, почему выдает ошибку?:)

```
def vowel_back(st): #testcase
    empty_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    new_list = ''
    for num in st:
        samo = empty_list.find(num)
        samo1 = ord(num)
        if samo1 == 97 or samo1 == 99 or samo1 == 106 or samo1 == 111 or  samo1 == 117 or samo1 == 121: #вместо 98 105!!!!!!!
            if num in empty_list:
                samo += 7
                new_list += empty_list[samo]
    print(new_list)

output = vowel_back("acy")
```

Comment: Выход за пределы списка в: `empty_list[samo]`. А так, опишите в вопросе задачу, не думаю, что найдутся желающие по вашему коду определить что вы хотели сделать :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте взять остаток деления `samo` на длину списка

```
empty_list[samo % len(empty_list)]
```